# Qt not working correctly

Tags: c++, qt

I have just installed Qt_SDK_Win_offline_v1_1_4_en.exe and run QT Creator.
I am working on Win7 64 bit.

I wanted to make simply app with form and button on it to test Qt. I choose New->Project QT Widget->Aplikacja Gui QT ---> then Desktop application.

When I run Play Button - that should build and run the application I get a message: that I should check path and privileges. I can't also run the exe files as administrator manually because windows give me message that I don't have privileges. I gave full privileges in file Properties but then after run I am getting error that I don't have mingwm10.dll.

Comment: What is the name of your executable file? Don't laugh -- in Windows 7, it makes a difference.

Comment: just simple names: b.exe, nienazwany.exe 
ps. I just copy dll files that windows requested but I get an error that the application is not run correctly. Its very strange, QT SDK installer takes almost 2GB and there are problems with basic things.

Comment: OK, it's not that then. (If your exe file has "patch" in its name, for instance, Windows 7 assumes it requires elevated privileges. Very stupid.)

Comment: Did you install default version QtSDK, or did you chose custom and by your self chose what to install. My Win7 64 broke yesterday, and i had to reinstall system. I installed Qt and it's working normally. Did you install minGw that is supplied with Qt or separately?  What is your QtSDK path and your project path? Do they contain polish letters? Where did you find that mingwm10.dll?

Answer (score 0):

> I gave full privileges in file Properties but then after run I am getting error that I don't have mingwm10.dll.

This means the library required can't be found in any of the locations Windows searches to find libraries.  The usual method to get around this is by making sure the folder containing the copy of mingwm10.dll which the Qt SDK installs is in your `PATH` environment variable. Here is [one](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/05/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/) of the many Google-able guides to settings those variables.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a partial solution, I could finally run the exe file.

First, something must have changed in my Windows7 because every new created folder (and files in it)had restrictions and noone could make all operations.

So, after changing properties of folder, I got message about missing dlls files, so I started to copy them from QT folder. There are at least a few different versions of each dll, and only one is correct, so I copy those form mingw folder bacause I used mingw compiler, and finally after copying 4-5 dll I run the exe file.

But this is not what I am expecting from app that install pack has almost 2GB...

thanks
m.